# Does there exist a continuous open map from the closed annulus to the closed disk?

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology, continuity

(Originally from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747632/does-there-exist-a-continuous-open-map-from-the-closed-annulus-to-the-closed-dis?noredirect=1#comment10073356_4747632), but crossposted here upon suggestion from the comments)

In this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3082693/a-function-f-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2-that-is-open-and-closed-but-not-cont?noredirect=1&lq=1), user Moishe Kohan provides an example of a non-continuous open and closed ("clopen") function $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ for $n\geq 3$ by citing and using the following propositions of David Wilson:

> Propositions 1 and 3 of
>
> [D. Wilson, Open mappings of the universal curve onto continuous curves. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 168 (1972), 497–515.](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1972-168-00/S0002-9947-1972-0298630-0/S0002-9947-1972-0298630-0.pdf)
>
> [Moishe Kohan's] **Proposition** [cooked up from Wilson's propositions]. Let $I^n$ be the closed $n$-dimensional cube, $n\ge 3$, and $J^n\subset int(I^n)$ is a closed subcube. Let $Q$ denote the
> interior of $J^n$. Then, there exists an open continuous map $g: I^n\setminus Q\to I^n$ which equals the identity on the boundary of $I^n$ and
> sends $\partial Q$ to the interior of $I^n$.

I am interested in the $2$-dimensional case, for which I propose the following conjecture:

> **Conjecture:** there are **no** continuous open (w.r.t. subspace topologies) maps $f$ from the closed annulus $\mathbb A:= \{x\in \mathbb R^2: 1\leq |x|\leq 2\}$ to the closed disk $\mathbb D := \overline{B(0,2)}$, which restricts to the identity map on the outer boundary circle $\partial \mathbb D = C(0,2)\subseteq \mathbb A$, and sends the inner boundary circle $C(0,1)$ to the interior of $\mathbb D$.

I was not able to prove or disprove this conjecture for even the **Simpler Case:** where $f$ maps the inner boundary circle $C(0,1)$ to the single point $0\in \mathbb D$.

---

---

---

Some attempts I made on the **Simpler Case**.

***Attempt 1:*** Because we want $f$ to be open, we in particular want any open neighborhood in $\mathbb A$ of any boundary point $b\in C(0,1)$ to map to an open set containing $0\in \mathbb D$, in particular containing some $B(0,\epsilon)$.

My idea was map circles $C(0,1+\eta)$ to circles $C(0,\eta)$, and to to "swirl"/"smear" the circles $C(0,1+\eta)$ more and more extremely as $\eta \searrow 0$, so that even a very small neighborhood $B(b,\delta)\cap \mathbb A$ of $b\in C(0,1)$ containing just a $\approx \frac{2\delta}{2\pi}$ fraction of the circles $C(0,1+\eta)$ for small enough $\eta>0$ would get "swirled"/"smeared" to contain the entire circle $C(0,\eta)$.

So something like $f$ maps $z:=re^{i\theta}\in \mathbb A$ (thinking of $\mathbb R^2$ as the complex plane) to $(r-1)e^{i\theta\cdot \frac{1}{r-1}}$, mapping an arc of the circle $C(0,1+\eta)$ of arclength $\ell$ to an arc of the circle $C(0,\eta)$ with arclength $\ell \cdot \frac{1}{r-1}$. Unfortunately, the corresponding formula for $f$ would be $$f(z)=\frac{|z|-1}{|z|^\frac{1}{|z|-1}} \cdot z^{\frac{1}{|z|-1}},$$ which maybe looks fine, until one remembers that raising a complex number to a non-integer power needs (non-continuous) branch cuts to define. :(

---

***Attempt 2:*** One can make a continuous "swirling only" (no "spreading", i.e. no multiplicative factor in the argument variable) by mapping $r e^{i\theta} \mapsto (r-1) e^{i\theta + i\cdot \frac{1}{r-1}}$, i.e.
$$f(z) = \frac{|z|-1}{|z|} \cdot z \cdot e^{\frac{1}{|z|-1}},$$
which I think is continuous, and does "swirl" a very small neighborhood $N_b:= B(b,\delta)\cap \mathbb A$ to something that does sort of "wrap around" $0 \in \mathbb D$, but in doing so has a lot of holes: this $f$ preserves that proportion of the arclength of $N_b \cap C(1+\eta)$, meaning $\text{arclength}(N_b \cap C(1+\eta)) = \text{arclength}(f(N_b) \cap C(0,\eta))$, so $f$ can't possibly map $N_b$ to something containing $B(0,\epsilon)$.

---

***Attempt 3:*** Finally, because of this "monodromy problem" of defining this "swirling/smearing" map on the entire circle $C(0,1+\eta)$, I had an idea of cutting up $C(0,1+\eta)$ into $\frac 1\eta$ many pieces (restricting to $\eta \in \{\frac 1n: n=2, 3, 4, \ldots\}$), making $f$ "swirl/smear" each of those pieces into the entirety of $C(0,\eta)$, thus guaranteeing that $f(N_b)$ contains complete circles $C(0,\eta)$ arbitrarily close to $0\in \mathbb D$.

More precisely, I would partition $C(0,1+\frac 1n)$ into $2n$ equally sized, equally spaced pieces, and define $\{K_{n, i}\}_{i=1}^n$ to be the closures of the say odd-indexed pieces. I can map $K_{n,i}$ continuously to cover the entirety of $C(0,\frac 1n)$. Then for any $N_b:= B(b,\delta)\cap \mathbb A$, it does contain some $K_{n,i}$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, and hence $f(N_b)$ contains $C(0,\frac 1n)$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.
I can extend this $f$ defined on $C(0,1) \cup \bigcup_{n=2}^\infty\bigcup_{i=1}^n K_{n,i}$ via the [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) to a continuous function $\mathbb A \to \mathbb D$, but again I really doubt it is a an open map.

---

---

---

So as it stands regarding the **Simpler Case**, I can't even find a continuous function $f:\mathbb A\to \mathbb D$ that maps the neighborhood $B(b,\delta)\cap \mathbb A$ (for even a single fixed $\delta>0$) of any point $b\in C(0,1)$ to an open set containing $0\in \mathbb D$; nor can I disprove its existence.

*---(EDIT: user1789 posted an answer that was later found to be incorrect and hence deleted, but if I recall correctly, that answer was able to map the inner boundary in "an open manner", but pushed the issue into the interior of the annulus. Those with sufficiently high reputation should be able to see this attempt.)---*

Of course, one possible route of proving the **Conjecture** is if one accomplishes the original MSE post's goal of proving that every clopen function $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ must be continuous (as for example is true in the $\mathbb R^1 \to \mathbb R^1$, as I showed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737384/does-there-exist-a-non-continuous-clopen-function-g-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r)), but I suspect that problem is even harder than this one.

Comment: But it is possible if you allow the inner boundary of the annulus to also map to the boundary of the disk, right? With radial segments in the annulus going to diameters of the disk.

Comment: @NikWeaver seems like it'd work. However, I do specify in the full statement of the Conjecture (although not the title) that the inner boundary of the annulus should map to the interior of the disk.

Comment: What about identity map? It disproves your conjecture.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko The image of the closed annulus is not open in the closed disk under the identity map.

Comment: @D.R. hence my use of the word "IF".

Comment: The last condition of the conjecture is that the map sends the inner circle of the annulus in the interior of the disk, so how can this map be open? A neighborhood of a point on the inner boundary of the annulus is open in the topology of the annulus. And the image of this neighborhood cannot be open in the disk.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I don't follow your argument. If we ignore the rest of the annulus, and restrict attention only to the neighborhood $U$ of a point on the inner boundary of the annulus, then certainly the image of $U$ can be open in the disk. For example, if $D$ denotes the open unit disk $\{z \colon |z| < 1\}$ in the complex plane, then the image of $\{z\in D\colon \Im z \ge 0\}$ under the map $z\mapsto z^2$ is $D$.

Comment: @Timothy Chow: but in your example, the image of a neighborhood of a nearby point on the boundary of the half-plane is not open. An open map cannot send a point of the border to an interior point.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I'm still missing something. Where does your argument break down in 3 dimensions?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: yes, an open map can send boundary points to interior points: it will map a half-disk onto a full neighborhood of the image point.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: can you give an example?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: Not explicitly and not in dimension 2 but dimensions $\ge 3$: See the reference to Willson's paper given in OP.

Comment: It seems that an example of such an open map from the annulus to the disk (mapping the interior circle of the annulus to the center of the disk) does exist. However, the construction is a bit involved and will require some time to write down the details.

Comment: Unfortunately, my construction of an open map from the annulus to the disk dot not work, so we should think on the proof of the conjecture and not on constructing an example.